# Fiddler cause http error 502

Tags: google-chrome, http, fiddler

I run a web server on localhost. When trying to go to  https://localhost:9002
for some reason Fiddler cause http error 502 when trying to browse it on Chrome .
When I stop Fiddler - there is no problem to reach the site .
All other internet site include https works fine with Fiddler

Comment: What is the body of the HTTP/502 message in Fiddler? Look at the Response `TextView` Inspector. Does your server only listen on ipv4 or ipv6?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Go to your project location and find there .vs folder

.vs/config/applicationhost.config

try to delete or rename (applicationhost.config) and Visual Studio will generate new file.